# How can we start navigation in our own app Google Maps SDK iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, navigation

How can we start navigation between two routes when taken from the Google Directions API.

Any ideas where to go from here? How can I manage to integrate the navigation from one route to another in our own App?

I am getting the routes from the google directions API and it is being shown in my App. But how can I start the navigation between them using my current location not using google map app but in our own app?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're asking a board question which doesn't have code in it indicating what you have done so far, so, assuming you want to know what steps you have to do, here is the answer:

if you have gotten the destination coordinates, longitude & latitude, you can pass them to your instance of the MapKit, and you got the destination.

The starting point, which in this case is the user's location can be asked from the user by accessing it in by adding `Privacy - Location Always Usage` in your info.plist file. 
Then you can start routing between the Two locations.

I highly encourage you to read more on Apple's [CLLocation framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocation) which lays the outline of this with extra details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that i am using Google Maps SDK, not Apple SDK.

Comment: @HarjotSingh so do you want what APIs to use or how to do it? Have you checked the SDK reference, guidance and sample?

Comment: What i have checked so far is that there is no API for turn by turn navigation. So, this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme is saying we can open google maps for a turn by turn navigation, but i am not clear how to do it can u please explain?

Comment: Yes Google Map SDK doesn't provide public APIs for it. But there are some workarounds, you can implement the navigation by your self, or take a look at OpenStreetMap & Scout SDK